# Qareen allocated to each person

Tags: jinn

Salams to all,
 i would like to know if it is possible to "get rid" of the jinn (qareen) that is allocated to each person as every person has their own that whispers to them. Some of us know and may have witnessed jinn being "taken out of people" thus my question if the qareen can be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Qareen cannot be removed. Let's look at the wording of this Hadith (In [Sahih Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/52/62))

> عَنْ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ مَسْعُودٍ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏ مَا مِنْكُمْ مِنْ أَحَدٍ إِلاَّ وَقَدْ وُكِّلَ بِهِ قَرِينُهُ مِنَ الْجِنِّ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ قَالُوا وَإِيَّاكَ يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ قَالَ ‏"‏ وَإِيَّاىَ إِلاَّ أَنَّ اللَّهَ أَعَانَنِي عَلَيْهِ فَأَسْلَمَ فَلاَ يَأْمُرُنِي إِلاَّ بِخَيْرٍ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
>
> Abdullah b. Mas'ud reported that Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said: There is
>   none amongst you with whom is not an attache from amongst the jinn
>   (devil). They (the Companions) said: Allah's Messenger, with you too?
>   Thereupon he said: Yes, **but Allah helps me against him and so I am
>   safe from his hand and he does not command me but for good.**

Allah (SWT) could have removed the Qareen of His Prophet (PBUH) instead of helping His Prophet (PBUH) against that Qareen.